# Pagination with JQuery, PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination

> The Problem: When I click on a pagination link the script is generating the new html table content, but it's not refreshing the table in the browser.

I have class user with method called `showUsers($limit, $offset)` which is fetching all the data I need and displaying it in table.

```
  <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-default">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Nickname</th>
        <th>User ID</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php $user->showUsers($limit, $offset); ?>
  </table>
```

this is my offset varaible: `$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit`, `$page` is the number of the pressed pagination link.

This is how I generate the pagination links:

```
  <div class="col-sm-9 mx-auto">
    <?php
      for ($i=1; $i <= $allPages ; $i++) {
        echo "<span class='pag-link' id='$i' style='cursor: pointer; padding: 6px; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 3px;'>". $i. "</span>";
      } 
    ?>
  </div>
```

This is my JS Script:

```
    //pagination-link handler.
    $('.pag-link').click(function(){
      var page = $(this).attr("id");
      console.log(page);
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "info.php",
         data: {page: page},
         success: function(data){
             console.log(data); // show response from the php script.
         }
       });
   });
   setInterval(function(){ $(`#table`).load('info.php #table'); }, 1000);
```

Note: `setInterval(function(){ $("#table").load('info.php #table'); }, 1000);` should get the HTML in the table and update the table in the browser with the new table.

So when I click, a page the number is send in the info.php file. This changes my `$offset` variable and the `showUsers($limit, $offset)` method will generate new table with different data.
Now this is working because I'm seeing all new HTML that is generated in the javascript console, but `setInterval(function(){ $("#table").load('info.php #table'); }, 1000);` is not working and my table is not update.

> Note: I want to refresh the table in interval, because if multiple users input data I want it to be updated to everyone in real time.

Comment: Somone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.load('info.php #table') doesn't have the page parameter.

So you load the page ("info.php"), click the next pagination link (url: "info.php",data: {page: page}), and that works, but then the timer loads info.php again, replacing the data.

This will require moving the "var page;" to the top of the Javascript, outside the function call:

```
    //pagination-link handler.
    var page=1;
    $('.pag-link').click(function(){
      page = $(this).attr("id");
      console.log(page);
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "info.php",
         data: {page: page},
         success: function(data){
             console.log(data); // show response from the php script.
         }
       });
   });
   setInterval(function(){ $(`#table`).load('info.php?page='+page+'#table'); }, 1000);
```

The PHP that fills $offset will need to respond to both GET and POST, such as $_REQUEST.